# Use Oracle INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH datatype in Access

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle11g, ole, sqldatatypes

I'm working with Oracle 11g and Access 2016 with ODBC on Windows 10, I'm trying to display on a datasheet a table that has a column defined with datatytpe INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH, but when querying Access shows me OLE Object instead of for example +01-00.

How can I make it appear correctly?

Comment: Which driver/provider do you use?

Comment: Oracle's 11g driver: SQORA32.DLL version 11.02.00.02
I'm not sure what do you mean for provider, but I think it's Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library

Comment: Can you just use a query to populate the datasheet that casts it to a string? Access doesn't have anything even remotely close to such a data type, so won't be able to understand it.

Comment: Solved :) Thank you, I had not even thought about it